# Remove switch from switched outlet

Tags: switch, receptacle

I have a two 3-way switch switched outlet.

I want to remove both switches and replace both with blanks, thus capping the wires in the box so that the outlet is always on and there is no switch in between.

My house was built in 2001.

United States electrical code.

Using the diagram below... Someone on another site suggested capping the Black/Red/White of Switch A together, and then capping the Black/White/Black of Switch B together to remove both switches but keep outlets powered all the time.

[image: Wiring Diagram]

UPDATE:

I capped all three wires (Red/Black/White) of Switch A but left Switch B alone for now. This resulted in the outlet always being on regardless of Switch B's On/Off position.

Tomorrow I will try the same with Switch B, and I assume this will work. Would be nice to have clarification to make sure this is not going to cause a fire.

Comment: On each switch, which wire color is attached in the position with a different colored screw?

Comment: Switch A: Red wire = Black screw; Black/White wires = Silver screw

Comment: Switch B: Black wire (left side) = Black screw; Black/White wires (right side) = Silver screw

Comment: Switch C: Black wire (lower right side) = Black screw; Black/Red wires (higher on switch) = Silver screw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take switch B's black wire (black screw) and connect it to the red wire going to the outlet.  All remaining wires connected to switch A and switch B can simply be capped individually as they are now unused.

(edit: this paragraph originally existed to dispute a second answer that has since been deleted) This method of wiring a 3-way uses a 3 conductor cable for common and two travellers to be transported to switch A.   The White between switch A and switch B is not a neutral in this  case.